# Facing problem in Linq to sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

//Below mentioned class is created to understand the problem, while this is created through Linq2Sql.

```
public class JobAds
{
 public int ID  { get; set; }
 public int EmployerRef { get; set;}
}

int? employerId = null;

var jobAdListing = JobAds.Where 
     ( n => (!employerId.HasValue || n.EmployerRef == employerId.Value )).ToList();
```

The Issue is I'm getting "Nullable object must have a value." at the above line. After doing some debugging, I feel n.EmployerRef == employerId.Value is making some trouble, but unable to find anything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write liks this, you don't have to worry about the null values (since NULL == NULL equals false)

```
int? employerId = null;
var jobAdListing = tblCompanies.Where 
     (n => (n.fkUserID_responsible == employerId)).ToList();
```

Or you can keep your code and just remove the ".value"

```
var jobAdListing = JobAds.Where 
     ( n => (!employerId.HasValue || n.EmployerRef == employerId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Good shot dude, take a virtual High Five from my side. Btw, I used the second option by removing the ".value".

Answer (score 1):

in my local playground a simmilar case works with this easiest approach:

```
using (UnitOfWork.Begin("LinqToSql"))
{
    Guid? id1 = null;
    Guid? id2 = this.personRepository.GetAll().First().FavouriteProjectId;

    var all = this.personRepository.GetAll().Where(o => o.FavouriteProjectId == id1 || o.FavouriteProjectId == id2).ToArray();
}
```

for you, this should work too:

```
int? employerId = null;
int? employerType = null; /* OTHER Conditions */

var list = JobAds.Where(n => n.EmployerRef == employerId &&
                             n.EmployerTypeRef == employerType)).ToArray();
```

Comment: NET employerId is a local variable. But, I can't user IF condition over here, because I have around 6 local variables similar to employerId and you can imagine how many IF conditions I required. That's why, I'm using (!employerId.HasValue || n.EmployerRef == employerId.Value ) kinda code over here.